# How to fetch detail from image

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am working on a android app that show the details of a book from server.
Now i have to add a new feature :- when user scans any image of the book from app. So open the details of the image in app
Is their is any way to store index in book image and fetch from app.

I did not find any possible solution of this problem if any one have idea how to done this. Please help me

Comment: I'm doing the same project. Can we collaborate and share our knowledge thought the project.

Comment: What frameworks do you use.(Ionic or React)

Comment: i am using Native Android framework

Comment: It's not hybrid, isn't it? What is the IDE?

Comment: it's Native android app and IDE is Android studio

Comment: No prob! I'll move on to android studio would you like to get together with me. These days I'm researching and struggling how to image processing. I have an interesting video collection too. What is your idea?